# How to reverse words in a string instead of reversing the whole string?

Tags: javascript, string, reverse, in-place

```
function reverseInPlace(str) {
    var words = [];
    words = str.split("\s+");
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        return result += words[i].split('').reverse().join('');
    }
}
console.log(reverseInPlace("abd fhe kdj"))
```

What I expect is `dba ehf jdk`, while what I'm getting here is `jdk fhe dba`. What's the problem?

Comment: `return` inside a multi-iteration for-loop ?!

Comment: I don't understand,,,can't I do this?

Comment: As an aside: "In place" doesn't mean what you seem to think it should. An "in place" operation would act like: `s = 'abd fhe kdj'; reverseInPlace(s); console.log(s)`.

Comment: `"abd fhe kdj".split( " " ).map( s => s.split("").reverse().join( "" ) ).join( " " )`

Comment: if u return a function inside a loop. loop will not run entirely it will itereate only once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to split the string by space

```js
function reverseInPlace(str) {
  var words = [];
  words = str.match(/\S+/g);
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
     result += words[i].split('').reverse().join('') + " ";
  }
  return result
}
console.log(reverseInPlace("abd fhe kdj"))
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you tell me why "split" does not work when I try to split the string into array on the third line?

Comment: @XinyiLi if you want to split the string using regex you cannot double quotes you can use like this `str.split(/\s+/);`

Comment: yup absolutely!

Answer (score 10):

This function should work for you:

```
function myFunction(string) {
    return string.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ")
};
```

Answer (score 5):

`Split` the string into words first before reversing the individual words

```
var input = "abd fhe kdj";
var output = input.split( " " ).map(  //split into words and iterate via map
     s => s.split("").reverse().join( "" )  //split individual words into characters and then reverse the array of character and join it back
).join( " " ); //join the individual words
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are looking like this o/p : "Javascript is Best" => "Best is Javascript"**

Then can be done by simple logic

```
//sample string
     let str1 = "Javascript is Best";
//breaking into array
     let str1WordArr = str1.split(" ");
//temp array to hold the reverse string      
      let reverseWord=[];
//can iterate the loop backward      
     for(let i=(str1WordArr.length)-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
//pushing the reverse of words into new array
          reverseWord.push(str1WordArr[i]); 
     }
//join the words array 
      console.log(reverseWord.join(" ")); //Best is Javascript
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const reverseWordIntoString = str => str.split(" ").map(word => word.split("").reverse().join('')).join(" ")

const longString = "My name is Vivekanand Panda";
const sentence = "I love to code";


const output = {
  [longString]: reverseWordIntoString(longString),
  [sentence]: reverseWordIntoString(sentence)
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `split` and `map` function to create the reverse words.

You need to first split the `sentence` using `space` and then you can just reverse each word and join the reversed words again.

```js
function reverseWord (sentence) {
  return sentence.split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return word.split('').reverse().join('');
  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(reverseWord("abd fhe kdj"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution **preserves the whitespaces characters** space `␣`, the tab `\t`, the new line `\n` and the carriage return `\r`) and preserves their order too (not reversed) :

```js
const sentence = "abd\t fhe kdj";

function reverseWords(sentence) {
    return sentence
        .split(/(\s+)/)
        .map(word => /^\s+$/.test(word) ? word : word.split('').reverse().join(''))
        .join('');
}

console.log(reverseWords(sentence));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to reverse a string by word:
Example: 'Welcome to JavaScript' to 'JavaScript to Welcome'

You can also do something like:
var str = 'Welcome to JavaScript'
function reverseByWord(s){
  return s.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}

// Note: There is space in split() and Join() method

reverseByWord(str)
// output will be - JavaScript to Welcome
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by the following code

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
    // Go for it
    let reversed;
    let newArray=[];
    reversed = str.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0;i<reversed.length; i++)
    {
        newArray.push(reversed[i].split("").reverse().join(""));       
    }
    return newArray.join(" ");
}
let reversedString = reverseWords("This is an example!");
console.log("This is the reversed string : ",reversedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only mistake is while doing split you can do something like:

```
function reverseInPlace(str) {
    var words = [];
    words = str.split(" ");
    console.log(words);
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
         result += words[i].split('').reverse().join('') +" ";
    }
    return result
}
console.log(reverseInPlace("abd fhe kdj"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverse(str) {
    var rev = str.split("").map(word => word.split("").reverse().join("")).join(" ")
    return rev
}

console.log(reverse("soumya prakash")); // aymuos hsakarp
```

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help with formatting code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let s = “getting good at coding needs a lot of practice”
let b = s.split(" ").reverse().join(" ")

console.log(b)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

-> Split the string into array of words `str.split(" ")`
-> map the each word and split into each characters `.map(word => word.split("")`
-> reverse the each word individually and join it

```
.map(word => word.split("").reverse().join("")
```

```js
const str = "abd fhe kdj";

const reverseWord = str => {
  let reversed = "";
  reversed = str.split(" ").map(word => word.split("").reverse().join("")).join(" ")
  
  
  return reversed
}

console.log(reverseWord(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

For people looking into this problem now, think whether your application doesn't need to deal with punctuation marks (e.g. not moving punctuation marks around) or flipped hyphenated words (e.g. check-in should be ni-kcehc or kcehc-ni ?).

For example:

- "ignorance is bliss?!" should really be "ecnarongi si !?ssilb" ?
- "Merry-go-round" should be "dnuor-og-yrreM" or "yrreM-og-dnuor" ?

The following solution doesn't move punctuation marks and it doesn't flip hyphenated words:

```
/**
* 1. Split "non letters"
* 2. Reverse each piece
* 3. Join the pieces again, replacing them by " "
* 4. Split all characters
* 5. Replace " " by the original text char
*/

function reverseWords(text) {
    return text.split(/[^A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]/g)
        .map(w => w.split("").reverse().join(""))
        .join(" ")
        .split("")
        .map((char, i) => char === " " ? text[i] : char)
        .join("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverseInPlace(str) {
  var words = [];
  words = str.match(/\S+/g);
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
     result += words[i].split('').reverse().join('') + " ";
  }
  return result
}
console.log(reverseInPlace("abd fhe kdj"))
```

Comment: Hi, you added no explanations.  "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better", as suggested in the help page. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
reverseStringBywords = (str) =>{
  let rev = ""
  str.split(" ").forEach(s =>{ 
      rev = rev + s.split("").reverse().join("") + " " 
  })
  return  rev
}
console.log("reverseStringBywords ", reverseByWord("JavaScript is awesome"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let reverseOfWords = (words) =>{
  _words = words.split(" ").map(word => word.split('').reverse().join(""))
   console.log("reverse of words ", _words.join(' '))

}
reverseofWords("hello how are you ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this reverseString().
This can be use for both 'reverse the entire string' and 'reverse each word'.

```js
function reverseString(string, separator) {
  return string.split(separator).reverse().join(separator);
}

const str = "See the magic of javaScript"

const reverseWholeString = reverseString(str, "");
console.log("Reverse the whole string ->", reverseWholeString);

const reverseEachWord = reverseString(reverseWholeString, " ");
console.log("Reverse each word ->", reverseEachWord);
```